# unlndir script to undo the results of lndir

Tags: shell-script

The `lndir` command performs a shadow copy of a directory tree, but using symlinks. Files are symlinked rather than copied, while subdirectories are copied. It works fine, but I also need some kind of `unlndir` script that performs the opposite.

In other words, the behavior of `unlndir` would be:

- If there's a symbolic link on the target tree pointing to a file in the source tree, remove the symbolic link.
- Perform previous task recursively for all subdirectories that exist in both the source and the target tree.
- If some subdirectory in the target tree becomes empty, remove it.

I realize this is similar to what [GNU Stow](https://www.gnu.org/software/stow/) does, but I am looking for a simpler shell-script based approach.

Do you know of any shell script that can do this?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming GNU `find(1)`:

```
find -P /some/dir -type l -xtype f -delete && find -P /some/dir -type d -empty -delete
```